# Get all records of relationship when parent doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two models.

Resource:

```
public function account()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Account');
}
```

Account:

```
public function resources()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Resource');
}
```

I want to receive all resources of an account knowing `user_id` from account Model.

```
Account::where('user_id', Auth::id())->first()->resources()->get();
```

This works only when account exists. It throws error otherwise: `Call to a member function resources() on null`.

What's the smart way to get all resources in Eloquent? The best would be to use only one query statement in the background, because I know above example is using two queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the `whereHas()` eloquent method to select all `Resources` attached to `account` who belongs to a specific `user_id`. Try this:

```
 $resources =  Resource::whereHas('account', function ($query)
        {
            $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
        })->get();
```

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence