# Query on multiple rows in related table in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table named `stocks`:

```
id | name
1  | Microsoft
2  | Tesla
```

This table has a one-to-many relationship with a table titled stock_ratings:

```
id | stock_id | measure | value
12 | 1        | revenue | 3000
13 | 1        | dividend| 5
14 | 2        | revenue | 1000
15 | 2        | revenue | 0
```

Now, I need to be able to search for stocks based on multiple ratings in the stock_ratings table. For example, if I need to find a stock that has `revenue > 0` and `dividend > 0`, then I should get Microsoft as a result, but not Tesla. I have been struggling to formulate this query.

I've tried using a join like this:

```
$query = DB::table('stocks')->select('stocks.id', 'name');
$query = $query->join('stock_ratings', 'stocks.id', '=', 'stock_ratings.stock_id');
$query = $query->where('stock_ratings.measure', 'revenue')->where('stock_ratings.value', '>', 0);
$query = $query->where('stock_ratings.measure', 'dividend')->where('stock_ratings.value', '>', 0);
```

But I keep getting results that have nothing to do with what I'm after. This makes sense because I suppose the tables are joined once and that's it.

How do I get the correct results here?

Comment: You will have to use eloquent relationship query. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219020/get-all-records-of-relationship-when-parent-doesnt-exist/65219102#65219102

Answer (score 0):

Without scoped querys:

```php
/* SQL Statement:

Select stocks.id,name from stocks 
join stock_ratings on stocks.id=stock_ratings.stock_id 
where stock_ratings.value>0 
and (stock_ratings.measure='revenue' or stock_ratings.measure='dividend')

*/ 

$query = DB::table('stocks')->select('stocks.id', 'name')
         ->join('stock_ratings','stocks.id','=','stock_ratings.stock_id')
         ->where(['stock_ratings.value','>',0])
         ->where(function ($query) {
               $query->where('stock_ratings.measure','revenue')
                     ->orWhere('stock_ratings.measure','dividend');
           })
         ->get();
```

---

Using scoped querys:

At your `stocks` table model `Stock.php` define a function:

```php
/*I would recomend you use a shorter name, but for the answer purpose...*/
public function scopeFindByNameWhereRevenueDividendGreater($name,$revenue,$dividend){
        return $query->where('name',$name)
                    ->whereHas('stockRatings', 
                        function ($q) use ($revenue,$dividend) {
                            return $q->where([
                               ['measure', '=', 'revenue'],
                               ['value', '>', $revenue]
                             ])->orWhere([
                               ['measure', '=','dividend'],
                               ['value', '>', $dividend],
                             ]);
                        }
                    );
}
```

then use `Stock::findByNameWhereRevenueDividendGreater('Microsoft',0,0);` instead.

Comment: I need to use a raw query, not relations. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.

Comment: @svetipetar I added the query that might help you get the right answers. This will always get positive dividends and positive revenues.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use Eloquent.
First, create Rating Model, associate to table ratings.

In Rating Model :

```
public function stock()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\Stock');
}

public static function scopeMeasure($query, $test)
{
  return $query->where('measure', $test);
}

public static function scopeHasRatingValue($query)
{
  return $query->where('value', '>', 0);
}
```

After use :

```
Rating::measure('revenue')->measure('dividende')->hasRatingValue()->stock;
```

I didn't try but i think it will work

Comment: I need a solution without using Eloquent because of some performance issues (there are other parts of the query).

Answer (score 0):

How many types of measures would you possibly have? If not a lot, e.g. only revenue and dividend, I'd recommend having them as separate columns in your table and having their values default to 0, that way you only need to chain where statements in your query:

```
$query->where('revenue','>',0)->where('dividend','>',0);
```

Comment: This won't work. Look at the structure closely. Revenue and dividend are in separate rows of a related table.